Stata is not saving my statistics to the table
I have the following code:
eststo A: estpost ttest infoAll if VR==0, by(PC)
eststo B: estpost ttest infoAll if PC==0, by(VR)

esttab A B using infodelivery.rtf, replace   ///
cells("b(fmt(3) pattern(0 0 0 1 1 1)) mu_1(pattern(1 1 0 0 0 0 )  fmt(2))  mu_2(pattern(0 0 1 0 0 0 )  fmt(2))" ) nostar unstack label nonum noobs nogaps mlabels("Phone Call" "Voice-Recorded Audio" "Difference") collabels(none)

But every time I run the esttab line of code, my table shows up empty as the following:

table output
Can anyone help me out? I do not understand why this is the case. I am trying to get a table that looks like this but only the column that has all information delivered:

table i want to replicate
I tried running that code with different formatting multiple times but I get the same empty table. Stata for some reason is not saving the results and I don't know why.
I am not able to attach my data file here however, you can access it through this link: https://dataverse.harvard.edu/file.xhtml?fileId=4771542&version=1.0 . It is titled is_4_4_6_publicData.dta
Thank you!

A good question would be self-contained and include all the (minimal) data and code that are sufficient to reproduce the problem. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
